# The difference between 0 and 128

Tags: c++, c, cpu-architecture

An `signed integer` (using 8 bits) --- Range==> `-128 to 127`.

And if we consider the 2's Complement representation:

```
10000000 =128/(-0) [ Since its 2's Complement is 10000000 ]
```

So in a way its a `negative` zero.

Now for a `signed` integer, 128 is `1000 0000` and the 2's complement is also `1000 0000`, so don't we have a copy of `0` [ in the negative form as well ] using this representation? Or am is missing something?

Sorry for the typo. Yes the range is  `-128 to 127`.

But 8 bits can represent this number in memory `10000000`. If this number `CAN` be stored in memory then what is its value?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: There is no 128. Editing the question to fix the range but still talk about 128 is kind of silly.

Comment: 128 is the value in decimal of binary number `10000000`. I did not mean that IT IS in the range.

Comment: it's not in the range so it's not representable

Comment: I see people moving in circles without giving the exact explanation. Do not tell me this cannot be done because it is that way. I want to know why is it that way, what is the explanation. `it's not in the range so it's not representable` - Ok, but this gets stored in the memory does not it?

Comment: Will the Comp Sci majors please stand up!

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain We already did

Comment: If you store 10000000 in memory it's going to be -128. See my very first comment.

Comment: Lohit, you've moved from a reasonable question (based on a mistake you made about representation, but reasonable given your misunderstanding) to an open ended historical question about why computer architecture designers use 2s complement for `int` storage and whether that was a good idea. This is beyond StackOverflow's purpose. Wikipedia's article on 2s complement is probably better for giving you the background you need.

Comment: Two complements with wrap-around acts like modulo calculations. For convenience, we use the range -128 to 127 as "representations" of the equivalence classes. You can pick others, but it doesn't change anything. Thus 256 also acts as a zero in 8 bits two complements. So does any other multiple of 256. If you want a negative "zero", take e.g. -256. Or -1024. They all are in the same equivalence class as 0 for modulo 256 calculations.

Comment: Soon this will degrade into an argument about how many original Star Trek episodes there were.  The correct answer is 78.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain Is that answer in hex of base-13?

Comment: @Dough Chamberlain Lies.  Every geek knows it's 42!

Comment: @MGZero it is 42, in base 19 :P

Comment: @Sjoerd: "Hex of base 13"? Base 16 of base 13? :)

Comment: @Doug: what, you mean excluding the unoriginal ones? About half of them.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody mentioned that abs(-128) is negative.  It's a common bug, if not one that pokes it's head much.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: `abs` takes an `int`, guaranteed to be at least 16 bits, so `abs(-128)` is positive. But ignoring that, calling `abs(INT_MIN)` on a two's complement system results in undefined behavior, it is not guaranteed to be negative. In practice it probably is, but that's not to be relied on.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I'd say that a more elegant thing to mention is that there's a way to produce overflow by using integer division: by dividing `INT_MIN` by `-1`.

Comment: @Jonathan It should have been "hex or base-13". It's a common typo for me. Or rather, it is a common forgot-to-translate mistake, as the dutch translation for "or" is "of". And they are so simular, that it is easy to miss during proof-reading and the spell checker won't catch it either.

Answer (score 8):

No, a value of 10000000 for a signed integer is not 128, it's -128.  The most significant bit is used as a sign bit.

Comment: Sorry, I edited your post instead of mine.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the fact that the range of an 8 bit number in 2's comp is -128 to 127, not -127 to 128.  You're also misunderstanding how 2's comp works, and you're treating it as [sign and magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method).

2's comp cycles when it reaches it's max value, you can't simply read by looking at the sign bit, then looking at the remaining bits as a normal value, then combining the two.  That would be sign and magnitude.  e.g.

- 10000001 - This is -127, *not* -1
- 10000010 - This is -126, *not* -2
- 10000011 - This is -125, *not* -3

> "But 8 bits can represent this number in memory 10000000. If this
>   number CAN be stored in memory then what is its value?"

It's value is -128.

Answer (score 2):

"in a way it's a negative zero."

It's in *no* way a negative zero. The two's complement of `x` by definition is `~x+1`, and (assuming 8 bit arithmetic), `~0+1` is `0000 0000`, not `1000 0000`. So *zero* is a negative zero.

As you say, the two's complement of `1000 0000` is `1000 0000`, so that's the other value which is its own negation.

In an unsigned binary representation, `1000 0000` represents 128. In 8 bit two's complement representation it represents -128 (which is consistent with the fact that -127 is `(~0111 1111)+1`, i.e. `1000 0001`). It can't represent both 128 *and* -128, so it has to be one or the other. Choosing -128 has the nice property that then the first bit is always `1` for negative numbers and `0` for non-negative ones, and hence can be called the "sign bit".

Comment: I know its not. You did not understand the question.

Comment: @Lohit: ah well, if you knew that it is not "in a way a negative zero", then you could have saved me some time by not saying that it was. Fortunately I can tell you what `10000000` represents, and why, without understanding every subtle nuance of the question.

Comment: +1 for calling out OP's nonsense about "negative zero".

Answer (score 1):

The range is `-128` to `127`, and ***not*** `-127` to `128`. `-128` is coded as `0b10000000`. Note that the top bit is the sign bit, so `0b10000000` is negative. The two's complement of `-128` is indeed `128`, but that falls outside the range of your integer and can't be represented by it.

If your integer were 16 bit, `-128` would be represented by `0b1111111110000000` and `128` by `0b0000000010000000`. The lower byte is indeed the same, but the rest of the integer is different, and that matters!

So your conclusion that `128`, or `-128`, is, er... invariant WRT two's complement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

10000000 is not (-0). It does not act as (-0) in any addition.

E.g.: 1 + (-0) = 0000 0001 + 1000 0000 = 1000 0001 = -127

Answer (score 0):

It is true that 8-bit pattern `10000000` can be interpreted as either `128` or as `-128`. It is just a matter of agreement.

If we agree to interpret it as `128`, then the 2-s complement range if 8-bit integer will be `-127..128`.

If we agree to interpret it as `-128`, then the 2-s complement range if 8-bit integer will be `-128..127`.

The standard 2's complement representation agrees to interpret `10000000` as `-128` since it is rather convenient to know that all representations with 1 in higher-order bit always represent *negative* numbers. So, in practice the range of signed 2's complement representations is always "shifted" slightly towards negative values.

P.S. It is not clear where "negative zero" comes into the picture. 2's complement has no negative zero.